# How can I add a parameter to a callback function like in JavaScript?

Tags: php, mysqli

I wanted to make a small function that let's me connect to the database, do something in a callback function and then automatically close the connection like so:

```
function mysqli_conn( $connection( $mysqli ) ) {
    $connection( new mysqli($c_host, $c_user, $c_password, $c_database ) );
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

Usage would be like this:

```
mysqli_conn(function( $mysqli ) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO some_table (info1, info2, info3, info4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $info1, $info2, $info3, $info4);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();     
});
```

Is it possible to achieve this somehow? Because my `mysqli_conn` doesn't seem to work.

How to do it?

Comment: Why though? If you do this more than once you're going to wind up with a lot of overhead creating connections to run a single statement, and the connection is implicitly closed once the variable goes out of scope and/or the script ends anyway. This smells like you're treating your PHP app as though it's persistent beyond a single request [it's generally not], or that your code might run in an indefinite order like JS. [it won't]

Comment: I didn't know it was such a big deal.. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Hey, for all I know you've got a definite use-case that needs accomplishing via callback, but it's worth clearing up if it helps people avoid some common footguns/misconceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing the `$c_...` are globals / defined in the same file:

```
function mysqli_conn( $connection ) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli($c_host, $c_user, $c_password, $c_database );
    $connection( $mysqli );
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't put the callback's parameter in the definition of the function. Assign the variable in the function, then pass it to the callback.

You also need a `global` statement in order to access all the `$c_XXX` variables.

```
function mysqli_conn($connection) {
    global $c_host, $c_user, $c_password, $c_database;
    $mysqli = new mysqli($c_host, $c_user, $c_password, $c_database );
    $connection( $mysqli );
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

Comment: Please put back the original code. Now my answer makes no sense, since it refers to code that isn't there.